# WooCommerce Order By Price Not Working Correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When slecting the option sort by price (Woocommerce dropdown) the products to sort in price but it's not working exactly;
the first 6 are sorted:

- € 1,50
- € 11,75
- € 1,75
- € 1,75
- € 2,95
- € 4,50

Link to unfinished website:
http://verduijncichlids.com/product-categorie/vissen-voorraad/west-afrika-cichliden/?orderby=price

Anyone know what is happening and how to fix this?
Cheers!

Comment: Why do some products have a "," instead of a "." for euro cents delimiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `meta_value_num` when you order by numeric meta data, otherwise it will compared as strings otherwise because the post meta values are stored as strings in the database.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Which File do I need to add this in Woocommerce?

Comment: @Hassan This is the standard query for getting the list of posts(products) in WordPress/WooCommerce. Place it anywhere you want to print the list. You need to loop through the query results. If you don't understand this, this is probably not the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 18):

for anyone who may be faced with this problem

according to:
https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2019/04/01/performance-improvements-in-3-6/

if you imported your products with tools such as "WP All Import", you have to regenerate "Product lookup tables" in:

> WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Product lookup tables

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot, I really searched for few hours to find this right answer :)

Answer (score 6):

If ordering by price is not working correctly in WooCommerce a secure solution is always to customize how WooCommerce handles the ordering by price. This works because WooCommerce `price` and `price-desc` are default ordering options. (Tested with standard theme in WordPress v5.4.1 & WooCommerce v4.1.0):

in your functions.php add:

```
/**
 * Customize ordering by price
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', function ($args) {
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));

    if ('price' == $orderby_value) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    }

    if ('price-desc' == $orderby_value) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    }

    return $args;
});
```

like @Pelmered mentioned it is important to use `meta_value_num` as the 'order_by' option so the ordering is done by number values and not string values. I changed the `meta_key` to '_price' though, because that is required in the WooCommerce version used and mentioned above.

Further reading:

[WordPress Documentation WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

[WooCommerce Documentation Custom sorting options](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/)

Comment: Somehow this still holds true with Woocommerce v4.5.1.

Comment: fixed my issues. note it hides products with no price set

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sorts out properly. See featured products, as they have priority.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Woocommerce plugin to the latest version. It was a bug in the plugin or you probably changed something in core functions.

Update helped me well with this and several other issues.